# Excel 2003, intermitent VBA error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a script that inserts VBA controls into a sheet, the script is started by clicking on a button.  Sometimes the script runs without error and runs 100% correctly.

Sometimes the script stops before completion and a "Microsoft Visual Basic" error is displayed:

Run-time error '-2147319764 (8002802c)':
Method 'Name' of object 'IMdcCheckBox' failed

All buttons excel 'End' and Help are disabled.

I have no idea why it is erroring and as I say sometimes it runs completely ok.

The script is looking through 43 rows inserting on each row 2 checkboxes, 1 label and a combo box, all controls are named according to type with a index appended to the name starting at 1 and running up to 43.

Here is the routine, sorry its a bit large:

```
    Public Sub btnGetInfo_Click()
        If False Then
    errHandler:
            Resume Next
        End If        
        Dim objColumns As Collection
        Dim objTables As Collection
        Dim objRS As ADODB.Recordset
        Set objColumns = New Collection
        Set objTables = New Collection
        Set objRS = objExecuteSQL()
    'Removed all checkboxes and labels
        If removeOLEtypesOfType() = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not objRS Is Nothing Then
            Dim objItem As Field, varExisting As Variant
            Dim blnPresent As Boolean
            Do While Not objRS.EOF
                DoEvents

                With objRS
    'Iterate through the fields
                    For Each objItem In .Fields
    'Is this field name already present in the columns collection?
                        blnPresent = False
                        For Each varExisting In objColumns
                            If varExisting = objItem.Name Then
    'Yes, flag it is present and stop search
                                blnPresent = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        If blnPresent = False Then
    'Look for the table name
                            Dim objSubItem As Property
                            Dim strTable As String
                            strTable = ""
                            For Each objSubItem In objItem.Properties
                                If objSubItem.Name = TABLE_NAME Then
                                    strTable = objSubItem.Value
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next
                            If Len(strTable) > 0 Then
                                Dim blnFound As Boolean, strAlias As String
                                Dim varTable As Variant
                                blnFound = False
                                For Each varTable In objTables
                                    If strTable = varTable Then
                                        blnFound = True
                                    End If
                                Next
                                If blnFound = False Then
                                    objTables.Add strTable
                                End If
    'Get the alias for this table
                                strAlias = Trim(strBuildTableRef(strTable))

                                If Len(strAlias) = 0 Then
                                    strAlias = "t" & objTables.Count
                                End If
    'No, add the new item to the collection
                                objColumns.Add strAlias & "." & objItem.Name
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
    'We have the columns, exit loop
                    Exit Do
                End With
            Loop
    'Close the recordset
            objRS.Close
            Set objRS = Nothing
    'Clear the columns range
            Dim objColumnHeadings As Range, objDBsheet As Worksheet
            Dim lngRow As Long, objCell As Range, objOLE As Object
    'MS controls
            Dim objMSorderCbo As MSForms.ComboBox
            Dim obMSfieldCbx As MSForms.checkbox
            Dim obMSorderCbx As MSForms.checkbox
            Dim objMSlbl As MSForms.Label
            Dim intItemIdx As Integer

            Set objDBsheet = getDBsheet()
            Set objColumnHeadings = objDBsheet.Range(COLUMN_HEADINGS)
            objColumnHeadings.ClearContents
    'Populate sheet
            lngRow = 0
            For Each varExisting In objColumns
    'Get the cell/row we will insert the controls at
                Set objCell = objColumnHeadings.Cells(lngRow + 1, 1)
    'Insert a checkbox to allow selection of the column
                Set obMSfieldCbx = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                                  ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1" _
                                , Left:=objCell.Left + CHECKBOX_FIELD_XPOS _
                                , Top:=objCell.Top _
                                , Height:=CONTROL_HEIGHT _
                                , Width:=CHECKBOX_FIELD_WIDTH).Object
                obMSfieldCbx.Name = CHECKBOX_FIELD_PREFIX & (lngRow + 1)
                obMSfieldCbx.Caption = varExisting
                obMSfieldCbx.Font.Name = "Arial"
                obMSfieldCbx.Font.Size = 8
                obMSfieldCbx.BackColor = &HFFFFFF
                obMSfieldCbx.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
                obMSfieldCbx.ForeColor = &H0
    'Insert a label
                Set objMSlbl = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                                  ClassType:="Forms.Label.1" _
                                , Left:=objCell.Left + CHECKBOX_FIELD_WIDTH _
                                , Top:=objCell.Top + 3 _
                                , Height:=CONTROL_HEIGHT).Object
                objMSlbl.Name = LABEL_PREFIX & (lngRow + 1)
                objMSlbl.Caption = "Order By:"
                objMSlbl.Font.Name = "Arial"
                objMSlbl.Font.Size = 8
                objMSlbl.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                objMSlbl.BackColor = &HFFFFFF
                objMSlbl.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
                objMSlbl.ForeColor = &H0
                objMSlbl.AutoSize = True
    'Insert combobox
                Set objMSorderCbo = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                                ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1" _
                              , Left:=objCell.Left + CBOX_OFFSET _
                              , Top:=objCell.Top _
                              , Width:=45 _
                              , Height:=CONTROL_HEIGHT).Object
                objMSorderCbo.Name = CBOX_PREFIX & (lngRow + 1)
                objMSorderCbo.Font.Name = "Arial"
                objMSorderCbo.Font.Size = 8
                objMSorderCbo.ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
                objMSorderCbo.MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone
                objMSorderCbo.TextAlign = fmTextAlignLeft
                objMSorderCbo.BackColor = &HFFFFFF
                objMSorderCbo.ForeColor = &H0
                objMSorderCbo.SelectionMargin = False
                objMSorderCbo.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
                For intItemIdx = 1 To objColumns.Count
                    objMSorderCbo.AddItem CStr(intItemIdx)
                Next
                objMSorderCbo.ListIndex = lngRow
    'Insert a checkbox to allow selection of asc/desc
                Set obMSorderCbx = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                                  ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1" _
                                , Left:=objCell.Left + CHECKBOX_ORDER_XPOS _
                                , Top:=objCell.Top _
                                , Height:=16 _
                                , Width:=16).Object
                obMSorderCbx.Name = CHECKBOX_ORDER_PREFIX & (lngRow + 1)
                obMSorderCbx.Alignment = fmAlignmentLeft
                obMSorderCbx.AutoSize = True
                obMSorderCbx.Caption = "Desc"
                obMSorderCbx.Font.Name = "Arial"
                obMSorderCbx.Font.Size = 8
                obMSorderCbx.BackColor = &HFFFFFF
                obMSorderCbx.BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
                obMSorderCbx.ForeColor = &H0
                obMSorderCbx.TextAlign = fmTextAlignRight
                lngRow = lngRow + 1
            Next
    'Start timer this is necessary due to bug in the way activeX objects
    'are registered
            startTimer
    'Get the tables from the database
            Dim objTableNames As Range, objTablePrefixes As Range
            Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command
            Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
            Set conn = openDB()
            Set objTableNames = objDBsheet.Range(TABLE_NAMES)
            Set objTablePrefixes = objDBsheet.Range(TABLE_PREFIXES)
            objTableNames.ClearContents
            objTablePrefixes.ClearContents
            lngRow = 1
            With cmd
                .ActiveConnection = conn
                .CommandText = "SHOW TABLES"
                Set objRS = .Execute()

                Do While Not objRS.EOF
                    Set objCell = objTableNames.Cells(lngRow, 1)
                    objCell.Value = objRS.Fields(0).Value
                    Set objCell = objTablePrefixes.Cells(lngRow, 1)
                    objCell.Value = "t" & lngRow
    'Next record
                    objRS.MoveNext
                    lngRow = lngRow + 1
                Loop
    'Close the recordset
                objRS.Close
                Set objRS = Nothing
            End With
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Probably impossible to answer without seeing the code.  Maybe put in a call to `DoEvents` after creating the control to make sure Excel can instantiate it completely?

Comment: Tried that, still does it, the code is quite large.

Comment: Hmmm... and you can't reproduce it with a smaller test case?

Comment: Code is now posted, let me know if you need any of the called subroutines or functions.

Comment: Are you referring the `DoEvents` in the recordset loop?  Or have you tried putting them after the calls to `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add`?

Comment: I just tried adding a call to DoEvents after each 'ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add', same result it errors.

Comment: It seems to be every other call fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118256/discussion-between-comintern-and-splatten).

Comment: Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Still no idea why this is failing intermittently, would welcome suggestions on how to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I wrote a function to execute the SQL statements and this trapped the error.

```
    Public Function objExecuteSQL(Optional ByVal strSQL As String = "") As ADODB.Recordset
    'Start off by initialising function return in case of failure
        Set objExecuteSQL = Nothing

        On Error GoTo errHandler

        If False Then
    errHandler:
            Debug.Print "Error in objExecuteSQL:" & Err.Description
            Resume Next
        End If

        If Len(strSQL) = "" Then
            strSQL = Trim(Sheet1.txtSQL.Text)
        End If
        If Len(strSQL) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No SQL statement to execute", vbCritical
            Exit Function
        End If
    'Connect to database
        Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
        Set conn = openDB()
    'Create command to perform query
        Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = conn
            .CommandText = strSQL
            Set objExecuteSQL = .Execute()
        End With
    End Function
```